# Cannot find module 'generator-jhipster'

Tags: node.js, jhipster, yeoman

I am trying to load the "generator-jhipster' inside Yeoman as is described on the Yeoman documentation:

http://yeoman.io/authoring/integrating-yeoman.html

```
var yeoman = require('yeoman-environment');
env.register(require.resolve('generator-jhipster'), 'jhipster:app');
```

The "generator-jhipster' and "generator-jhipster-entity-audit" modules are installed in node and in the app, in fact, I can use the "generator-jhipster" from the "yo "command without problems, but when I run my node Script, it give me the error:

```
module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'generator-jhipster'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\DANI\Randoop\JHIPSTER\server.js:6:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

Any idea about how to solve this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved.

The jHipster genetator don't have the index.js on the main folder, so, the correct code to invoke it is:

```
var yeoman = require('yeoman-environment');
var env = yeoman.createEnv();
env.register(require.resolve('generator-jhipster/generators/app'), 'jhipster:app');
```